# TypeScript+Node.JS web-development framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm looking for something like Play(Java) or Symfony(PHP) framework but written in TypeScript for Node.JS, unfortunately had no luck to find one. Maybe someone can point me to the right direction?

Comment: You can take a look at theses framework: http://typeframework.com/, http://gnd.io/

Answer (score 2):

Using TypeScript doesn't mean cutting yourself off from JavaScript libraries.  All the compiler needs is a declaration file to tell it how you're supposed to use the JS library.  They exist for most of the popular libraries, but Node.js framework support seems to be more sparse.  The only declaration file I found was for [Express](http://expressjs.com/) with the file available [here](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/express).  Fortunately it's quite popular and should be a good place to start.

Comment: Unfortunately I need more then express. I guess I should collect/port some libraries by myself

Comment: You don't have to port the library, just write the declaration file that describes it.  It's much less work.  This guide is quite good: http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201301/Blog/Complex-TypeScript-Definitions-Made-Easy/

Comment: Thank you Jeffery, i know about declarations and numerous JS libraries. However if you'll investigate you'll find that most of serious web frameworks have automatic scaffolding and code generation. It will be difficult to keep declarations synchronized with autogenerated code.

Comment: Interesting.  This is a world I don't know much about.  It looks like the amount of code generation varies between frameworks.  Still you don't need to port an entire library, just modify the code generator.